# How does one save tasks in their expected states and order even after the browser has been closed?

Tags: javascript

Currently working on a To Do List app project. How does one save tasks in their expected states and order even after the browser has been closed?

Comment: Submit the data to a server

Answer (score 0):

You either save your data to a server or in your case which I suppose you don't have a server, you can use localStorage : [you can read about local storage here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)